# Creating Uniform Binning with Turf JS

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, visualization, turfjs

I'm working on a visualization project in which I need to use Turf JS (bbox) to create hexagon bins on a map, developed using MapBox. Anybody has experience with Turf JS in creating hexagon bins or can point me in a direction? Much love!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 class, for the `navbar` "black" and for the `button` class
"white"

simple:

```
.black {
background-color: black;
}

.white {
background-color: white;
}
```